# Less can't find path for @plugin in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, less

So in my main LESS file, I would have two lines:

```
@plugin "{}/src/imports/views/stylesheets/plugins/colors.js";
@import "{}/src/imports/views/stylesheets/colors/categories.less";
```

The `@import` works as expected, but the `@plugin` throws an error

```
Unknown import: {}/src/imports/views/stylesheets/plugins/colors.js
```

Why is it behaving like that?

I'm using `less@2.7.11`

Comment: `{}` is not a part of the Less language, neither any `2.7.11` version exists. Both most likely are `meteor` specific` things and I wonder if it supports the `@plugin` statement at all (you''ll need to consult its documentation).

Answer (score 1):

While Meteor uses less v2.5.0, the first version to support `@plugin` rules, [their asset compiler](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/less/plugin/compile-less.js) does not support the loading of files with the import syntax used by `@imports` in Meteor.

Loading should still work using relative paths

---

#### Detail

Meteor's compiler only implements the [`AbstractFileManager`](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/12fe0c6f507485aaec6b519373d9b7f38ac950a4/lib/less/environment/abstract-file-manager.js) interface which loads imported files for less in a Meteor app.

In order to support abstract loading of plugins in meteor, it would also have to implement the [`AbstractPluginLoader` interface](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/environment/abstract-plugin-loader.js).

The good news is that this doesn't look too difficult. I'd start by copying the [PluginLoader for Node.js environments](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/12fe0c6f507485aaec6b519373d9b7f38ac950a4/lib/less-node/plugin-loader.js) and modifying it to do the same thing as the [`MeteorImportLessFileManager`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/less/plugin/compile-less.js#L111)

If you can get it to work, the Meteor community would love to get a PR from you to implement this.